# Is it possible to load an external file with Spring Mail configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I currently have the following content under my mail-config.xml in my Spring MVC app, but I want to load this parameters from an external file placed ie in /var/etc/myconfig/mail-config.txt, is that possible?

I'm specially interested in placing the host and auth credentials for the smtp server, thanks

**mail-config.xml**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.example.com" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />     
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PropertySource if you went down the annotated method, otherwise there is no equivalent for XML configuration.

There are ways to hack this in a sense and here is a good example of how to achieve that:

[Define Spring @PropertySource in xml and use it in Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738623/define-spring-propertysource-in-xml-and-use-it-in-environment)